# Listing all available shared libraries on a Galaxy S III

Tags: java, android, galaxy, shared-libraries

I have an unrooted Galaxy S III and would like to know what additional libraries are available on this device when compared to a stock Google Nexus. I'm especially interested in .so libraries regarding Bluetooth Low Energy, as Samsung claims to be "Bluetooth Smart Ready" with the GS3.

- How can I enumerate available libraries on an android device?
- How can I load the library? (`System.loadLibrary`?)
- Do I also need to include a `<uses-library />` directive into the manifest file?

Comment: I have tried with `PackageManager` enumeration of installed applications, and using the `sharedLibraries` property of each application in hope that all shared libraries are used somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Use `adb` to connect your device and try to `find` *.so files then create an emulator device for Nexus and try to `find` .so files in it. Finally, you can comapre results and find out which libraries are different.

Actually you cannot load library. `ld` does it for you. Write your native code and link it to the related library.

AFAIK, `<uses-library />` is not for that purpose.